# Firestore Permission Denied in Android on Test Rules

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am first time using firestore, I am facing problem of Permission Denied, I found many solution in SO but still can not be able to solve my problem.

Here is my code

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
                val db = Firebase.firestore

            val city = hashMapOf(
                "name" to "Los Angeles",
                "state" to "CA",
                "country" to "USA"
            )

            db.collection("cities").document("LA")
                .set(city)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Timber.d("DocumentSnapshot successfully written!")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Timber.d("Error writing document ${e.message}")
                }
        }
```

My Firestore rules are

```
service firebase.storage {    
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {    
      allow read, write: if true;    
    }    
  }    
}
```

As you can see I have set public rules so anyone can edit update or delete record.

Still I am getting permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is the problem,

Created another project run(In Android Studio and Firebase), same code with same rules.

Works well!!

Wasted mine 3 hours :(